# Generators + async/await, yielding asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, generator, ecmascript-next

I have 2 very related questions.  One practical, relating to a real problem I have, and one more theoretical.  Let me start with the latter:

### Q1: Does async/await + generators make sense?

In general, it doesn't make too much sense to have yield inside of callbacks or promises.  The problem (among others) is there could be races between multiple yields, it's impossible to tell when the generator ends, etc.

```
function* this_is_nonsense() {
   setTimeout(() => { yield 'a'; }, 500);
   setTimeout(() => { yield 'b'; }, 500);
   return 'c';
}
```

When using async/await these problems seem to actually mostly go away

```
function timeout(ns) {
   return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ns));
}

async function* this_could_maybe_make_sense() {
   // now stuff is sequenced instead of racing
   await timeout(500);
   yield 'a';
   await timeout(500);
   yield 'b';
   return 'c';
}
```

I assume nothing like this is currently possible (please correct me if wrong!).  So my first question is, is there a conceptual issue with using generators with async/await?  If not, is it on any kind of roadmap?  It seems like implementation would require more than just mashing together the two features.

### Q2: How to write lazy wiki crawler

This is a contrived version of a real code problem I have.

Imagine writing a function that does traversal of Wikipedia, starting from some arbitrary page and repeatedly following links (doesn't matter how - can be depth first, breadth first or something else).  Assume we can *asynchronously* crawl Wikipedia pages to get linked pages.  Something like:

```
async function traverseWikipedia(startLink) {
  const visited = {};
  const result = [];
  function async visit(link) {
     if (visited[link]) { return; }
     visited[link] = true;
     result.push(link);

     const neighboringLinks = await getNeighboringWikipediaLinks(link);

     for (const i = 0; i < neighboringLinks.length; i++) {
        await visit(neighboringLinks[i]);
     }

     // or to parallelize:
     /*
     await Promise.all(
       neighboringLinks.map(
         async (neighbor) => await visit(neighbor)
       )
     );
     */
  );
  await visit(startLink);
  return result;
}
```

This is fine... except that sometimes I only want the first 10 links, and this is gonna crawl over tons of links.  Sometimes I'm searching for the first 10 that contains the substring 'Francis'.  I want a lazy version of this.

Conceptually, instead of a return type of `Promise<Array<T>>`, I want `Generator<T>`, or at least `Generator<Promise<T>>`.  And I want the consumer to be able to do arbitrary logic, including asynchronous stopping condition.  Here's a fake, totally wrong (i assume) version:

```
function* async traverseWikipedia(startLink) {
  const visited = {};
  function* async visit(link) {
     if (visited[link]) { return; }
     visited[link] = true;
     yield link;

     const neighboringLinks = await getNeighboringWikipediaLinks(link);
     for (const i = 0; i < neighboringLinks.length; i++) {
        yield* await visit(neighboringLinks[i]);
     }
  );
  yield* await visit(startLink);
}
```

This is the same nonsense from Q1, combining async/await + generators as if it did what I want.  But if I *did* have it, I could consume like this:

```
function find10LinksWithFrancis() {
   const results = []
   for (const link of traverseWikipedia()) {
      if (link.indexOf('Francis') > -1) {
          results.push(link);
      }
      if (results.length === 10) {
          break;
      }
   }
   return results;
}
```

But I could also search for different number of results and strings, have asynchronous stopping conditions, etc.  For example, it could show 10 results, and when the user presses a button, keeps crawling and shows the next 10.

I'm okay with just using promises/callbacks, without async/await, as long as I still get the same API for the consumer.

The *caller* of the generator can do asynchronous things.  So I think it's possible to implement this, where the generator function yields the promise of neighbors, and it's up to the caller to call `gen.next` with the resulting actual neighbors.  Something like:

```
function* traverseWikipedia(startLink) {
  const visited = {};
  function* visit(link) {
     if (visited[link]) { return; }
     visited[link] = true;
     yield { value: link };

     const neighboringLinks = yield { fetch: getNeighboringWikipediaLinks(link) };
     for (const i = 0; i < neighboringLinks.length; i++) {
        yield* visit(neighboringLinks[i]);
     }
  );
  yield* visit(startLink);
}
```

But that's not very nice to use... you have to detect the case of an actual result vs. the generator asking you to give it back an answer, it's less typesafe, etc.  I just want something that looks like `Generator<Promise<T>>` and a relatively straightforward way to use it. Is this possible?

Edited to add: it occurred to me you could implement this if the body of the generator function could access the Generator it returned somehow... not sure how to do that though

Edited again to add example of consumer, and note: I would be okay with the consumer being a generator also, if that helps.  I'm thinking it might be possible with some kind of engine layer underneath, reminiscent of redux-saga.  Not sure if anyone has written such a thing

Comment: There is a proposal for that: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration

Comment: @Bergi wow not sure how I missed it, it's already in babel-preset-stage-3.  that pretty much answers my question!

Comment: FWIW, nothing of that has anything to do with ES7.

Comment: right, thanks for fixing that